# Google Map API Javascript Vs Google Map SDK IOS

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I draw circle on MapView using Google Map SDK for iOS .

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(60,90);   
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
                                         radius:8000000];
circ.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
circ.zIndex = 23;
circ.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];
circ.strokeWidth = 2;
circ.map = mapView_;
```

In output it is not shading the region which is in the circle region.
On drawing with same lat and long (center) on Google Map API for javascript it is shading all region that is in the circle. Replace following code in the link.

```
 var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(60,90);
 var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
    center:amsterdam,
    radius:8000000,
    strokeColor:"#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity:0.8,
    strokeWeight:2,
    fillColor:"#0000FF",
    fillOpacity:0.4
    });
```

[Output in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_overlays_circle)

Question is how to draw circle in Google Map SDK for iOS like javascript API that will shade all region that is in the circle?

Comment: I think you have to set the `circ.fillColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255 green:122.0/255 blue:254.0/255 alpha:1.0];`. Not sure how blue you want but hope this helps.

Comment: Basically It is not drawing circle properly . Your code fills the color in wrong circle .

Comment: It is because of your `8000000` radius. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/Circle?hl=en#example) says:  "Note that the current map renderer is unable to draw the circle fill if the circle encompasses either the North or South pole. However, the outline will still be drawn correctly."

Comment: @gerardnimo  Any alternate method would you suggest??

Comment: I can't understand why it works perfect on web but not in a device ? 
Is there any logic behind this ??????